# Is there a standard way to convert JSON to Dataframe? Or do different cases require different solutions?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to understand how to convert a URL that consists of JSON, to a dataframe. I'm testing this sample code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.chsli.org/sites/default/files/transparency/111888924_GoodSamaritanHospitalMedicalCenter_standardcharges.json')
print(r.json())
```

That gives me this:

```
{"name":"Good Samaritan Hospital Medical Center","tax_id":"11-1888924","code":"57320","code type":"cpt","code description":"Closure of abnormal drainage tract from bladder into vagina","payer":"humana - medicare advantage","patient_class":"O","gross charge":"23452.80","de-identified minimum negotiated charge":"769.90","payer-specific negotiated charge":"3154.88","de-identified maximum negotiated charge":"3154.88","discounted cash price":"4690.56"}
{"name":"Good Samaritan Hospital Medical Center","tax_id":"11-1888924","code":"57320","code type":"cpt","code description":"Closure of abnormal drainage tract from bladder into vagina","payer":"HEALTH FIRST","patient_class":"O","gross charge":"23452.80","de-identified minimum negotiated charge":"769.90","payer-specific negotiated charge":"769.90","de-identified maximum negotiated charge":"3154.88","discounted cash price":"4690.56"}
: 421
```

Now, if I try t throw everything into a dataframe, like this...

```
df = pd.read_json(r.json(), orient='index')
print(df.head())
```

I am getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

I think there may be a customized way of doing this, but I am not sure. How can I convert this JSON into a dataframe? Are there different ways to do this based on different scenarios of how JSON is structured?

Comment: That can't happen with the code you wrote. You just assigned `df` on the line before, it can't be undefined. That error message has nothing to do with converting the JSON, it's a variable scope issue.

Comment: I think it's ': 421' at the end. I think that's what's throwing it off. I don't know JSON well enough to tell for sure what's happening here.

Comment: That URL doesn't contain valid JSON. It's multiple JSON objects, each on a separate line, but it should be an array of JSON objects.

Comment: But if there's a problem reading the JSON, you should get an error from `pd.read_json()`, not the line after it. Are you reading the JSON in a function then trying to print it in the caller? If you didn't have `global df` in the function you'd get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas.read_json doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

> Any valid string path is acceptable. The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. A local file could be: file://localhost/path/to/table.json.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("http://raw.githubusercontent.com/BindiChen/machine-learning/master/data-analysis/027-pandas-convert-json/data/simple.json")
print(df)
```

Comment: That's so simple, but too simple, I guess. When I run that code on the URL that I posted, I get this result:     loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None

ValueError: Trailing data

Comment: I see how it works now! You need ',lines=True' after the .json. Here's the full working code.

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("https://www.chsli.org/sites/default/files/transparency/111888924_GoodSamaritanHospitalMedicalCenter_standardcharges.json", lines=True)
print(df.head())

Comment: Oh, and thanks a ton for sharing that GuiEpi!!!

Comment: with pleasure! @ASH